# Passing PFObjects from indexPath.row through UIButton in TableViewCell Parse

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, segue, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a social app.  I have a UIButton inside a TableViewCell.  This button is called commentButton.  What I want to achieve with this button is for the user to tap it and goto a tableview where the comments for that post are held.  The issue is-----is that I am having a super hard time trying to pass the PFObjects at the current indexPath.row through a segue.  I have tried multiple things.  But let me help you get a better understanding of my problem.

[image: What My Cell Looks Like]

As you can see above, it's the comment button that I am trying to initiate the segue on.  commentButton has a tag of 222.  I have tried changing the class of the button to a NSINTEGER:

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
CommentButton *commentButton = (CommentButton*) [cell viewWithTag:222];
commentButton.index = indexPath.row;
[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
commentButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

**Calling Segue @Selector**

```
 -(void) commentSegue 
{
   NSLog(@"Button TOUCHED!");
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showcomments" sender:self];
}
```

**Prepare for Segue**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showcomments"])
        {

        CommentsViewController * cvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        if([sender isKindOfClass:[CommentButton class]]){
            CommentButton * button = sender;
            _currentPost =[self.objects objectAtIndex:button.index];
            cvc.postObject = _currentPost;
        }
    }
```

I have tried multiple things, this current code crashes with an ***unrecognized selector sent to instance*** error.

**I have also tried:**

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showcomments"]){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        PFObject *currentObjects = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CommentsViewController * cvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"Segue Objects: %@", currentObjects);
        cvc.postObject = currentObjects;
    }
```

But when my tableView is populated my NSLog prints out the same data no matter what cell I choose.  It's unable to differentiate which cell im choosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `self` to `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. I'm assuming you mean to be sending your button as the sender? (You later try to cast `sender` as a `CommentButton` in `prepareForSegue:sender:`) Try changing this:

```
-(void) commentSegue 
{
   NSLog(@"Button TOUCHED!");
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showcomments" sender:self];
}
```

To this:

```
-(void) commentSegueWithButton:(CommentButton *)button
{
   NSLog(@"Button TOUCHED!");
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showcomments" sender:button];
}
```

Then you need to modify the following:

```
[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

To be this:

```
[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentSegueWithButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also, while you are at it, create a breakpoint for All Exceptions if you don't have that already. That breakpoint will tell you at what line you are getting the unrecognized selector error.

Comment: JOSH you devil dog you!  Ugh, i wanna slap my forehead! ha!  Thanks bro!  This has been driving me nuts!